# 404 not found in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

This is controller **College.php**:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class College extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('College_model');
        }

        public function index() {
            $this->load->view('college_view');
        }

        function get_autocomplete() {

            if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
                $result = $this->college_model->search_college($_GET['term']);

                if (count($result) > 0) {
                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                        $arr_result[] = array(
                            'name' => $college_name,
                            'description' => $row->college_description,
                        );
                        echo json_encode($arr_result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This is **College_model.php**

```
<?php
    class College_model extends CI_Model
    {
        function get_all_college() {
            $result = $this->db->get('college');
            return $result;
        }

        function search_college($name) {
            $this->db->like('college_name', $name, 'both');
            $this->db->order_by('college_name', 'ASC');
            $this->db->limit(10);
            return $this->db->get('college')->result();
        }
    }
?>
```

This is view page **college_view.php**

```
<div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0 m-auto" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        <form action="http://vufind.carli.illinois.edu/vf-aru/Search/Home" method="get" role="search" target="vufind" name="searchForm">
            <div class="input-group lrcInputs">
                <input value="1" name="start_over" type="hidden">
                <label></label>
                <input class="form-control" id="college" name="college" type="text" placeholder="Search for books, ebooks, & media">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success lrcSearchButton" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#college').autocomplete({
                        source: "<?php  echo site_url('college/get_autocomplete'); ?>",
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            $('[name="college"]').val(ui.item.name);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

How to remove the error of 404 not found. if need more code or file i will help.

i m getting error in chrome console as  GET http://localhost/apluscollege/college/get_autocomplete?term=as 404 (not found)      jquery.min.js
i m making a search bar using autocomplete using jQuery ana ajax

Comment: simply the `source` for `autocomlete` is wrong as there is no reference to the exact PHP script, so you have to include `college.php` in that URL, like `http://localhost/apluscollege/college/get_autocomplete/college.php?term=as`

Comment: @mitkosoft i m using codeigniter 3 not in core  php

Comment: this is nothing related to codeigniter actually. so what do you get here `echo site_url('college/get_autocomplete');` as output?

Comment: Can you put the code of the config file here? Have you removed the index.php from the URL? Outputting the `site_url('college/get_autocomplete');` may help in answering your question